# Проблема с запуском приложения на Android 6 из-за иконки в оповещениях

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio, android-notification

При запуске приложения на API 23 компилятор студии выдает следующую ошибку.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid
>   small icon): Notification(pri=0
>   contentView=hitrene.pomegranate3/0x1090085 vibrate=null sound=null
>   defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)

Как я понял, ошибка — в неправильно подобранной иконке, но я пробовал все варианты (белая, черная, с прозрачным фоном, без него, png, xml и прочее), но ничто не хочет работать. Пробовал  изменить разрешение до 16*16 по ответам к [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188689) вопросу.
Изменение targetSdk до 21 — не лучший вариант. На Lolipop, кстати, все работает.

```
Context context  = getApplicationContext();
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarm)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle("Pomegranate")
                .setContentText(time);
Notification notification = builder.build();
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

> UPD: решение - понизить в build.gradle app до targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: Попробуйте  `NotificationCompat.Builder` вместо `Notification.Builder`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению, не помогло. Пробовал и v4.app.NotificationCompat и v7.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: По приведённой вами ссылке ещё говорится о том, что иконка должна быть белой... Вы пробовали передавать белую иконку?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, пробовал чисто белую png картинку как 64*64, так и 16*16

Comment: UPD: изображения, с которым начались проблемы брал [отсюда](https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/alarm), обычные png создавал в фотошопе

Comment: Т.е. с другими изображениями было нормально? Если так, то, видимо, вы что-то не то с ними сделали)

Comment: Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188689/android-lollipop-notification-builder-setsmallicon#comment54120352_27287420) ещё пишут (как я понял), что картинка должна быть белой и использовать альфа канал. Что конкретно имеется в виду - не знаю, я не дизайнер)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Так это и есть обычные png-шки:) Насколько я знаю, это единственный формат, который поддерживает прозрачность

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нет, не работает вообще с любыми( Первоначальные я брал оттуда

Comment: @КириллМатросов, других идей у меня нет( И воспроизвести у себя не могу - нема девайса с 6 андроидом.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня тоже, сам через Genymotion сижу) Все равно спасибо)

Comment: @КириллМатросов, возможно дело в самом эмуляторе. Попробуйте эмулятор гугловый (встроенный в студию) или воспользуйтесь сервисом тестирования, встроенным в консоль разработчика в маркете.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и это тоже не помогло. Ладно, буду искать решение дальше)

Comment: @КириллМатросов, возможно ещё дело в последних версиях либ (или в том, что они наоборот устаревшие). Попробуйте их обновить/понизить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб забавно, это сработало. Я просто думал, что при более ранней версии sdk он не запуститься на 6.0.0 +. Спасибо

Comment: @КириллМатросов, вы понизили `sdk-target`? Если да, то это, пожалуй, не самое изящное решение... Посмотрите ещё [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#notifications) - Возможно при сохранении последних версий надо просто как-то так так вызывать `setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context,R.drawable.alarm));`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб забавно, но теперь он ругается на неправльный формат (стоит int вместо некоего android.graphics.drawable,Icon

Comment: Ругается при последних версиях либ и таргетСдк?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ругается сама студия. на R.drawable.alarm, хотя в документации сказанно, что должно быть id

Comment: C API 23 метод может принимать `Icon`. Проверьте ещё раз что у вас последние либы и `targetSdkVersion=23`

Answer (score 2):

1. Добавьте папку drawable-xxxhdpi
2. Попробуйте иконку с альфа каналом, но только белый цвет, ни одного пикселя, отличающегося от #FFFFFFFF

Comment: Пробовал, но почему то не спасает. Не могли бы вы скинуть пример иконки, который будет работать? Может, я что то не так делаю...